# On Click show lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Simple Lightbox (http://simplelightbox.com) and have it all working, however I want to have a link that loads the lightbox and first image, instead of always having to click the images themselves.

I have tried this but it's not working.

```
    $(".launch-gallery").click(function () {
        lightbox.show();
    });
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console? If so, can you post them?

Comment: Nope, no errors

Answer (score 0):

Put the script tag at the end of the body tag;

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="lightbox.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(".launch-gallery").click(function () {
                lightbox.show();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

if the button with class launch gallery is dynamically added to the page or not rendered by the server, bind the click event to the document;

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="lightbox.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on("click",".launch-gallery",function () {
                lightbox.show();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Make sure also that the button has the class "launch-gallery";

`<button class='launch-gallery'>Launch</button>`